During evaporation, why would we expect temperature of the gas at the interface to be lower than the temperature of the liquid?
This paper says that, from the kinetic theory of gases, we expect temperature of the gas at the interface to be lower than the temperature of the liquid. Could the experts here please explain it?

Recently, models of the Boltzmann equation have been used to predict
the conditions existing at the interface of an evaporating liquid. It
was predicted that the liquid could evaporate only if the temperature
in the vapor were less than that in the liquid at the interface.
However, recent experimental studies have found the opposite relation
between the temperature in the vapor at the interface and that in the
liquid during steady-state evaporation. Using two different
experimental arrangements, a series of 20 experiments have been
conducted with water evaporating at different rates. In each
experiment, the temperature in the vapor at the interface was found to
be greater than that in the liquid.

